# How do I keep the width fixed in css?

Tags: html, css

In a hero section, how do I keep the width of the background fixed while only changing height?

Html:

```
<section id="hero">
<div class="container">
  <div class="info">
  <div class="img"></div> 
    <h1>This is a title</h1>
    <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur.</h2>
  </div>
  </div>
 </section>
```

Css:

```
#hero{
 height: 100vh;
 width: 100%;
 background: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.089), rgba(0, 0,   0, 0.089)), url(images/backgroundheader.png) no-repeat center /   cover;
 }
```

I want to be able to see all of the image from left to right and only change height while I resize the browser.

Currently, when I resize the browser the edges of the image(left and right) disappear.

Comment: Is this what youre looking for ? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit

Comment: Yes, so if the browser were larger and I didn't want the white borders I could use the "@media screen size"? Or is there a better way to prevent the lines using "contain"?

Comment: I wouldn't mind borders on top or bottom because I will probably move the image. As long as the image is resized and not cut.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the  tag element which is the height of the browser window.

```
html {
background: background: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.089), rgba(0, 0,   0, 0.089)), url(images/backgroundheader.png) no-repeat center fixed;

background-size: cover;
}
```